# I can't install stellar-base in python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, stellar

i tried installing Stellar-Base as it says here https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base but it doesn't work... i'm using a virtual environment and python3.
here is the error

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/sam/PycharmProjects/stellamomo/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/_crc16module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_crc16module.o
    src/_crc16module.c:22:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/sam/PycharmProjects/stellamomo/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-onsbk3g_/crc16/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-r5kwjf1o/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sam/PycharmProjects/stellamomo/venv/include/site/python3.6/crc16" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-onsbk3g_/crc16/
```

Comment: Do you have gcc installed?

Comment: yes, it has the latest version

Comment: You don’t have dev package of python, e.g python-dev the name might differ based on your OS

Comment: ohh is it that necessary to have a dev version? I'm on Linux... let me get it

Comment: Yes tell me if it resolves it